# ColdFusion 11 Data type preservation during serialization

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

I recently moved my code from CF9 to CF11 and I am having issues when I am trying to use `serializeJSON`. According to CF docs:

> Starting from ColdFusion 11, the data type is preserved during the
>   code execution time for Query and CFCs.
>
> SerializeJSON considers datatypes defined in the database for
>   serialization. If the database defines a column as a string, any
>   number inserted into the column will still be treated as a string by
>   SerializeJSON.

But I guess this is not the case....

When I am pulling data out of a varchar column in CF9 it comes out like this `"docid":"123"` which is what I want but in CF11 the same data look like this `"docid":123` and is causing an issue with what I am trying to do.

To be more specific, my ids look like this `2001101009460111385185` which is longer than what javascript can accept and they get converted into scientific notation. With the old format I didn't have this issue because my ids were treated as a string which is what I want.

```
Note: my code is exactly the same on both versions of CF
```

Anyone had this issue before and HOW did you go around it?

Code Sample
I am calling this function via an AJAX call, this function returns an array with a struct in it. When I dump the return value after I serialize the result I can see a JSON object in my console but the quotes are missing from all the number values. In a test file I created a simple query and then I am serializing the results and everything looks good......

```
 <cffunction name="locationData" returnformat="json" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="locationid" required="yes" type="string">
        <cfargument name="clientBrandid" required="yes" type="string">
          <cfscript>
            locationData = new mod_sigweb.components.xamplifierCFCs.location_info();
            result = locationData.getLocation(locationid,clientBrandid);
          </cfscript>          
        <cfdump var="#serializeJSON(result[1],'struct')#">
        <cfabort>
        <cfreturn #result#>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: Which CF11 update are you using? There was a bug fixed recently which was similar to this. In the case of the bug, it was converting the string "No" to false after it was serialized.

Comment: ColdFusion 11 Update 4 and there no other updates currently available. I created a test file and the serialization works but when I send it back to javascript from my function is removing the quotes from any numeric value

Comment: I have just tested the bug I mentioned in update 4 and it seems that its still broken. :/

Comment: That might be something different though because my test file just produced what I needed but the ajax response is still messing with me...

Comment: You will have to post some code to demonstrate what you are doing.

Comment: I guess so but my code is separated in 3 different files...

Comment: @Geo - It does not have to be the exact code you are using. Just a [small, stand alone, test case that reproduces the issue](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Leigh I made it work, the issue is I don't know why it wasn't working. I will post a sample code nonetheless because I would love to know what happened.

Comment: @Geo - Yes, that is one of the reasons for putting together a repro case whenever posting a question. In the process of yanking out the relevant code, reviewing it and putting it together again, you often figure out the issue on your own. If not, you at least end up with something others can run independently, so they can lend a second set of eyes to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate workaround that I have had to use for this bug is to concatenate a space to the end of the value

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(result)#">
    <cfset result[i].docid = result[i].docid & " "/>
</cfloop>
```

and then the js has to be aware of this (I know, it's bad) and remove that trailing space.